# Compiling PowerPC binary with gcc and restrict useable registers

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, powerpc

I have a PowerPC device running a software and I'd like to modify this software by inserting some own code parts.

I can easily write my own assembler code, put it somewhere in an unused region in RAM, replace any instruction in the "official" code by `b 0x80001234` where 0x80001234 is the RAM address where my own code extension is loaded.

However, when I compile a C code with `powerpc-eabi-gcc`, gcc assumes it compiles a complete program and not only "code parts" to be inserted into a running program.

This leads to a problem: The main program uses some of the CPUs registers to store data, and when I just copy my extension into it, it will mess with the previous contents.

For example, if the main program I want to insert code into uses register 5 and register 8 in that code block, the program will crash if my own code writes to r5 or r8. Then I need to convert the compiled binary back to assembler code, edit the appropriate registers to use registers other than r5 and r8 and then compile that ASM source again.

Waht I'm now searching for is an option to the ppc-gcc which tells it "never ever use the PPC registers r5 and r8 while creating the bytecode".

Is this possible or do I need to continue crawling through the ASM code on my own replacing all the "used" registers with other registers?

Comment: Why don't you save and restore the registers you need?

Comment: Yes, in theory I could do that by writing all registers onto the stack and reloading them when my code is done, but this has some disadvantages (in my opinion): When I just save all registers, I need to mess around with the stack pointer and its addresses if I actually wanted to permanently write to a register. If I only save the registers I need, I'd constantly need to check which ones I've modified, which changes should be permanent and which temporarily .... But if there is no gcc solution, I'll probably do that.

Comment: Problem is there is not only the compiler involved, btu also pre-compiled code like libraries - at least libgcc. Why not just store globals as expected in `.bss` or `.data`, i.e. stick to the ABI?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should think of another approach to solve this problem.

There is a gcc extension to [reserve a register as a global variable](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Global-Register-Variables.html):

```
register int *foo asm ("r12");
```

Please note that if you use this extension, your program does no longer confirm to the ABI of the operating system you are working on. This means that you cannot call any library functions without risking program crashes, overwritten variables, or crashes.

Comment: If it breaks the ABI depends. If the register is calle-saved by the ABI, there should be no problem. For ARM AAPCS, e.g. you can reserve r4..r12 (roughly) while still preserving the ABI. Not sure how that is for typical PPC targets.

Comment: And this "you cannot call any library functions" is because the function I try to call might try to use that "locked" register? That should be fine, if I ever need to call another function (which is unlikely in my extensions), I'll just check if it uses any of my "locked" registers. Thats what I did in the past, too, when I needed to call another function. 

Using the command you posted worked just fine, gcc issued some warnings ("call-clobbered register used for global register variable") but successfully gave me a binary which does not use those registers. Great!

Comment: @Olaf If the register is callee saved it might still be overwritten by library function you call.

Comment: @FUZxxl: No, because these are callees, thus have to save the register values. Unless you mean OP wants to call his patches also from libraries. But that's not how I understand the question.

Comment: @Olaf Ah yes, I see, I misread that. In this case, you are right. Be careful when there are callbacks though.

Comment: Looks to me loke a strange approach anyway. Actually, I'd go with using globals and follow the ABI otherwise. Looks like the cleanest way to be dirty.

Comment: @Olaf That's what I suggest, too. But I should not judge OP's intent.

Comment: On second thought: The global register will still cause problems when calling the patches from a library. Because that has no idea about e.g. `r12` being reserved as a global variable. You'd have to compiler **all** library modules with `r12` being reserved and your own code with the global. IOW: every code which does not know the global has to reserve `r12`, every other has it reserved by the global variable declaration.

Comment: Why is it important that the caller knows about reserved registers? I just want my code to not use that register(s). Other code parts not compiled by myself are able to use those registers just fine. Sure, reserving r3 and then calling a function will probably fail but I'll take care of it. I just wanted my own compiled C code not use specific registers in the resulting ASM bytecode.

Comment: @FlorianBach If that's all you want, then the approach listed above should work.